# Where can i find a Fluent NHibernate Tutorial?

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

I have googled and looked around does anyone know of any hidden gems out there that is not in first couple pages of a google search....

Comment: Good question! I've been looking fro soem getting started materials for this as well.

Answer (score 15):

The [wiki](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/) is your best bet. I've had a few [Fluent NHibernate posts](http://blog.jagregory.com/category/fluent-nhibernate/) on my blog, but most of that content is mirrored on the wiki anyway.

Comment: doesn't seem to exist anymore?

Comment: link is dead again. was probably: https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki?

Answer (score 7):

I appreciate this tutorial, perhaps can help you:

http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2008/09/17/value-objects.aspx

The author explain the concept of value object, using them like components.

Answer (score 6):

[That](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/ado_net/Your-very-first-NHibernate-application-Part-1.aspx) helped me a lot maybe you should try.

Answer (score 5):

[Here](http://nhibernate.info/blog/2008/09/05/a-fluent-interface-to-nhibernate-part-1.html) is a 4-part blog posting about FluentNHibernate.  Not sure exactly what you're looking for, but then you didn't say either. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Fluent Nhibernate has a [wiki](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/), have you checked it out?.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/161638-fluent-nhibernate-tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

This video tutorial added to youtube.com on 10/5/2011 got me up in running in about 30 minutes.
[Fluent NHibernate Tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HQcnLP0iYQo)

Update:  It's been a few months, but if you need advanced mapping and don't mind 3rd party tools, use DevArt's Entity Developer tool which creates all of your entities and mappings for up to 10 tables/entities for free.  The source code for the entity mappings is readily available for you to learn from.  If you look at it you can learn a lot.  http://www.devart.com/entitydeveloper/

Comment: This video is simply brilliant. Got me up and running within a few minutes.

Comment: I'm so glad I could help my English brethren out.  It's also very handy to have links to my research on stackoverflow.com.  I started a new project and had to reference this video.

Answer (score 1):

I like [NHibernate 3.0 tutorial with Fluent Nhibernate and LINQ 2 NHibernate](http://web.archive.org/web/20150829045748/http://www.d80.co.uk/post/2011/02/20/Linq-to-NHibernate-Tutorial.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The GitHub project page has got all the basic examples you need: https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Getting-started